# Order by FIELD along with subquery?

Tags: mysql

I want to order the query results by specific values.

Seems like I can use this:

```
SELECT
    column
FROM
    table
ORDER BY
    IF(
        FIELD(
            id,
            3,1,2
        ) = 0,
        1,
        0
    ) ASC,
    FIELD(
        id,
        3,1,2
    )
```

My problem is that `3,1,2` comes from another table column. Replacing `3,1,2` with (SELECT column from...) is not working properly. Because the SELECT returns the result as `"3,1,2"` and not as `3,1,2`

I can also extract `3,1,2` one by one, but in this case i get error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`.

What's the solution here ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the statement that returns the values `3, 1, 2` is something like this:

```
SELECT somecolumn FROM sometable ORDER BY someothercolumn
```

then you can use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to create a comma separated string that contains these values:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(somecolumn ORDER BY someothercolumn) col FROM sometable
```

and then use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) instead of [`FIELD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```
SELECT t.column
FROM table t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(somecolumn col ORDER BY someothercolumn) FROM sometable) s
ORDER BY 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.id, s.col) = 0,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.id, s.col)
```

I hope that I understood the logic that you want to apply to sort the table with your `ORDER BY` clause.